# Adding <script> to WordPress in <head> element

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to insert this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    some Javascript codes comes here
</script>
```

to WordPress' `<head></head>` section in front end and in admin panel

E.g., Joomla! 1.6 has an API that allows this:

```
        $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addCustomTag($headTag);
```

I need to add different things for different pages.  For example:

**Page 1**
I need to add

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="feed title" href="feed url" />
```

For a few pages

**Page 2**
I need to add

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" . LIVE_SITE .
 "/wp-content/plugins/jobs/lknlibrary/js/ajax.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">

    var ajax = new sack();
    var currentClientID=false;
    function getClientData()
    {
        var clientId = document.getElementById('db_country_id').value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        ajax.requestFile = '" .BASE_PATH . "/wp-content/plugins/jobs/com_jobs_admin/tasks/get_location_data.php?task=get_location_data&name=db_parent_id&getClientId='+clientId;    // Specifying which file to get
        ajax.onCompletion = showClientData; // Specify function that will be executed after file has been found
        ajax.runAJAX();        // Execute AJAX function
    }

    function showClientData()
    {
        clearJS = ajax.response;
        var strTagStrippedText = clearJS.replace(/(<\s*\/?\s*)div(\s*([^>]*)?\s*>)/gi ,'');
        document.getElementById('locationsDiv').innerHTML=strTagStrippedText ;
    }

    function initFormEvents()
    {
        if (document.getElementById('db_country_id')){
            document.getElementById('db_country_id').onchange = getClientData;
            document.getElementById('db_country_id').focus();
        }
    }

    window.onload = initFormEvents;
</script>
```

for a few pages

**Page 3**
I need to add

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/jobs/lknlibrary/js/tabs/tab.webfx.css" />
```

for a few pages

I have 70+ pages in admin panel like those above.

Trying to manage the header of the WordPress with the example is a bit difficult.

Comment: one is pure HTML and one is a PHP framework... they both result in the same HTML output. clarify your question please.

Comment: why not just paste your code in your header.php?

Comment: @JohnP that would indeed work in the front end, but not in the admin panel.

Comment: @pekka ah didn't see the admin panel comment. Best bet here would be plugin or filter I guess.

Comment: I realize that you're new here, but your edits to the question completely changed it. It would have been better to just accept the answer for the question you originally posed and create a new question for all of the additional info you added.

Comment: I believe that codex.wordpress.org is your best reference to handle this task very well depends on your needs check out these two pages on WordPress Codex: [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script "wp_enqueue_script") [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style "wp_enqueue_style")

Answer (score 165):

In your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function my_custom_js() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>';
}
// Add hook for admin <head></head>
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_js' );
// Add hook for front-end <head></head>
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_js' );
```

Comment: Good answer. A simple if/else statement would solve the rest of OP's requirements, i.e. checking for specific pages, page types and whatnot.

Comment: why `wp_head` and not `wp_enqueue_scripts`?
also, why `echo` instead of `wp_enqueue_script()`?

Comment: And what if it is already included by other plugins? Isn't it included twice?

Answer (score 18):

For anyone else who comes here looking, I'm afraid I'm with [@usama sulaiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909456/usama-sulaiman) here.

Using the enqueue function provides a safe way to load style sheets and scripts according to the script dependencies and is WordPress' recommended method of achieving what the original poster was trying to achieve. Just think of all the plugins trying to load their own copy of jQuery for instance; you better hope they're using enqueue :D.

Also, wherever possible create a plugin; as adding custom code to your functions file can be pita if you don't have a back-up and you upgrade your theme and overwrite your functions file in the process.

Having a plugin handle this and other custom functions also means you can switch them off if you think their code is clashing with some other plugin or functionality.

Something along the following in a plugin file is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Your plugin name
Description: Your description
Version: 1.0
Author: Your name
Author URI: 
Plugin URI: 
*/

function $yourJS() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script',
        plugins_url( '/js/your-script.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  '$yourJS' );
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' );

 function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url( '/css/your-stylesheet.css', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style' );
  }

?>
```

Structure your folders as follows:

```
Plugin Folder
  |_ css folder
  |_ js folder
  |_ plugin.php ...contains the above code - modified of course ;D
```

Then zip it up and upload it to your WordPress installation using your add plugins interface, activate it and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 5):

Elaborating on the previous answer, you can gather all the required snippets before outputting the header, and only then use an action hook to inject all you need on the head.

In your functions.php file, add

```
$inject_required_scripts = array();

/**
 * Call this function before calling get_header() to request custom js code to be injected on head.
 *
 * @param code the javascript code to be injected.
 */
function require_script($code) {
  global $inject_required_scripts;
  $inject_required_scripts[] = $code; // store code snippet for later injection
}

function inject_required_scripts() {
  global $inject_required_scripts;
  foreach($inject_required_scripts as $script)
    // inject all code snippets, if any
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.$script.'</script>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'inject_required_scripts');
```

And then in your page or template, use it like

```
<?php
/* Template Name: coolstuff */

require_script(<<<JS
  jQuery(function(){jQuery('div').wrap('<blink/>')});
JS
);

require_script(<<<JS
  jQuery(function(){jQuery('p,span,a').html('Internet is cool')});
JS
);

get_header();
[...]
```

I made it for javascript because it's the most common use, but it can be easily adapted to any tag in the head, and either with inline code or by passing a href/src to an external URL.

Comment: I wonder if this is the wordpress way. Any wp enthusiast cares to comment?

Comment: See also johnmackay61 answer below. I was not aware of wp_enqueue_script at the time of writing. Basically, my solution probably still applies to small snippets, but for bigger code you're better off by putting it on a separate js file and requiring it through the wp_enqueue_script function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok using an external plugin to do that you can use [Header and Footer Scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/) plugin

From the description:

> Many WordPress Themes do not have any options to insert header and
>   footer scripts in your site  or . It helps you to keep
>   yourself from theme lock. But, sometimes it also causes some pain for
>   many. like where should I insert Google Analytics code (or any other
>   web-analytics codes). This plugin is one stop and lightweight solution
>   for that. With this "Header and Footer Script" plugin will be able to
>   inject HTML tags, JS and CSS codes to  and  easily.

Comment: This would be the easiest way to manage that part of adding scripts to the footer or header. You may forget in the future how actually you added your code but with this, it is easier to remember.

Comment: It's a shame it seems unsupported now.  Might be worth updating the answer.

Answer (score -3):

One way I like to use is Vanilla JavaScript with template literal:

```
var templateLiteral = [`
    <!-- HTML_CODE_COMES_HERE -->
`]

var head = document.querySelector("head");
head.innerHTML = templateLiteral;
```