# How to snap to next section wihout using a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, jquery-plugins

I would like to enable/add the ability when visitors scroll that is snaps to the next section. Jquery plugins, such as [SmartScroll](https://d4nyll.github.io/smartscroll/) or [Fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) do exactly what I want. But, the problem is I don't know how to add these JS Plugins (coding ability is nonexistent) to my already existing Wordpress site, which was built with a bought theme and WP Bakery.

Is there a way to add this function (snap to next section) with no/minimal coding, by using a WordPress plugin.

If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: Please check the topic how to ask before asking a question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hope that this edit follows the guidelines.

Comment: do you want to use above jquery in wordpress site?

Comment: Yes, I want to use SmartScroll

Comment: 1. download these 3 jquery and include in your theme folder
`1. EventEmitter.min.js
2. lethargy.min.js
3. smartscroll.min.js`

and include in footer.php


2. initial in your footer.php

 `<script>
  var ee = new EventEmitter();
  $.smartscroll({
   sectionWrapperSelector: ".section-wrapper",
   sectionClass: "section",
   headerHash: "welcome",
   eventEmitter: ee
  });
 </script>`

Comment: @Ultra You need FTP access to your website, then 1. create a child theme 2. copy over header.php from the theme's folder to your child theme's folder 3. download the required scripts and put them in your child theme folder 4. implement them in header.php - All of this is explained elsewhere and can be found by googleing. Once you have a specific question and exhausted all other resources, come back here and edit your question.

Comment: @vel17  I've added the files to my child theme first, but didn't work, then to parent theme also didn't work. Do you need any more information that you would find useful for you to help me solve this issue?

Comment: @Chris G I've checked various sites and videos. They were from being too vague to expert level tutorial. For example, what you've mentioned to implemt them in header, many of the sites did not mention this and those that mention to "implement" put in another file.So, I've already "exhausted" them.

Comment: @Ultra Not sure what you found, but the first google result for "wordpress add script to header" is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849057/adding-script-to-wordpress-in-head-element - You can also simply insert a `<script>` tag directly into `<head>`, which is elementary HTML/JS knowledge. To be clear: I understand your situation perfectly, but your question is simply off topic for stack overflow. SO isn't a "how to" site.

Comment: I understand that it isn't a "How To" site. But, what other way do you formulate such a question? "i've copy/pasted a bunch of scripts and my site isn't working, here's what I did." It's better to ask: How do you do this properly, since what I did (follow bunch of Vloggers advice) didn't work


In anycase, I know how to insert a script to header, but if other blogs do not mention to do this. I would not go to the header and add the script. In any case, I did follow you step and still isn't working. And like I mention I have no knowledge of codes etc.

Comment: But, thank you for taking out the time for pointing me to the right direction

Comment: @Ultra "I have no knowledge of codes" is the reason why you cannot formulate the question in a way that isn't off-topic. When posting here, you are expected to have the required knowledge. - Anyway, can you get *any* JS code to run at all? What happens if you insert `<script> alert("test"); </script>`? Can you get that to run?

Comment: @Chris G Yes, the alert script does work

Comment: @Ultra Great, you can remove it again. Copy over footer.php, and insert the script tags from [here / How to use](https://github.com/d4nyll/smartscroll) into your own footer.php, right before `</body>`. However, replace `$.smartscroll(options);` with `jQuery.smartscroll(options);` and replace `path/to` with `<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>`

Comment: @Chris G Ok, I've added the scrip to my footer. What's the next step?

Comment: also on front-end this sentence appears: $ (document) .ready (function () { $ ('#eut-bg-wrapper') .smartscroll ();

Comment: @Ultra Not sure what's going on there, can you link me to your website so I can take look?

Comment: @Ultra G Sure [link website](https://staging.collagenicmachines.com/)

Comment: @Ultra You haven't closed all scripting tags, and your final `<script>` is after `</body>`. You're setting up smartscroll twice, the second time using `$`, which will not work in a Wordpress environment. If you look at the source in Firefox, you can easily see the syntax errors because the code highlighting is off.

Comment: Ok, I see where I messed things. I've double checked and:
- closed all the copied script tags
- moved the last script above </body>
- removed $ smartscroll
But, it still isn't working, I've even removed the last script to see if that was the problem and still nothing. Also, could it be that my section are name "eut-bg-wrapper" and not "section" (btw, I've already renamed sectionClass: "section" to eut-bg-wrapper. But, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not implement yet this snap feature even though [there are some attempts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2013/10/22/enabling-new-interoperable-panning-experiences-through-the-css-scrolling-snap-points-specification/) to do so.

Therefore you can only achieve such effect by using a Javascript library such as the ones you mention.

If you want to use it in Wordpress, then you'll have to find a wordpress theme or plugin that uses such Javascript library, for example, [Fullpane theme](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/utils/wordpress.html) from Themify, which uses fullPage.js.

I would recommend you with no doubt, to make use of [fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).
It is the most complete library of this kind, the most used and tested and it is maintained full time.