# Force plugin script to load in head

Tags: wordpress

I want to load my plugin's script in head, because it adds menu item which must be visible immediately without flashing. Pure JavaScript, so I don't need to worry about jQuery.

**I would like it to bypass popular functions.php script which moves scripts to the footer:**

```
// Move render-blocking JavaScript.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_clean_head', 9999999 );
function custom_clean_head() {  
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);   
   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
}
```

In my plugin I enqueue script this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin', 999999999 );
function my_plugin( ) {
    // assigning slug variables
    wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug, plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.min.js', array(), '', false); 
}
```

I thought that so low priority and `$in_footer` parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` being false would solve the problem, but script still loads in footer. What should I change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding <script> to WordPress in <head> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849057/adding-script-to-wordpress-in-head-element)

Comment: Not really, function which I included will move anything normally put in head to footer. I need to bypass it.

Comment: You can't "bypass" it. The function from above is removing WP's core functions from the `wp_head` action hook and reattaching them to the `wp_footer` action hook. You either insert your script some other way (like Artem suggested before, for example) or you remove that `custom_clean_head()` function so you can enqueue your script using the regular `wp_enqueue_script()` function. There's no other way around it.

Comment: just give a try to `wp_head` hook instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Hope that will do something different.

Comment: `wp_head`hook didn't work as well